# Saving an image from the web to the Saved Pictures folder in Windows Phone 8.1 RT C#

Tags: c#, image, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, dotnet-httpclient

How can I save an image to the Saved Pictures folder in Windows Phone 8.1 RT? I downloaded the image from the web using HttpClient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need this

```
var url = "Some URL";
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(url.LocalPath);
var thumbnail = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(url);

var remoteFile = await StorageFile.CreateStreamedFileFromUriAsync(fileName, url, thumbnail);
await remoteFile.CopyAsync(KnownFolders.SavedPictures, fileName, NameCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
```

You need to set the Pictures Library capability in your manifest.

Comment: This looks way nicer! I'll try it in a next version.

Comment: how to achieve the samething in Javascript ??

Answer (score 1):

I solved it thanks to mSpot Inc on the MSDN-forums. The code I use now:

```
StorageFolder picsFolder = KnownFolders.SavedPictures;
StorageFile file = await picsFolder.CreateFileAsync("myImage.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

string url = "http://somewebsite.com/someimage.jpg";
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

byte[] responseBytes = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);

var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

using (var outputStream = stream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
{
    DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(outputStream);
    writer.WriteBytes(responseBytes);
    writer.StoreAsync();
    outputStream.FlushAsync();
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to convert BitmapImage source to Btye Array, then use this byte array to save image, instead getting stream from url.

Actually i want to reduce usage of internet in my App.

Any help will be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to pick for the file location you need to use the [FileSavePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.filesavepicker.aspx) with [pictureLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.pickerlocationid.aspx) as the [SuggestedStartLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.filesavepicker.suggestedstartlocation.aspx).

If you want to save it without the user to select the destination you need to use something like this:

```
Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.picturesLibrary.createFileAsync
```

I believe in both cases you need to set the `Pictures Library` [capability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx) in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, I use this native implementation:

```
var url = new Uri(UriString, UriKind.Absolute);
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(url.LocalPath);

var w = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
var response = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(w.BeginGetResponse, w.EndGetResponse, null);
await response.GetResponseStream().CopyToAsync(new FileStream(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + @"\" + fileName, FileMode.CreateNew));
var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
await file.CopyAsync(KnownFolders.SavedPictures, fileName, NameCollisionOption.FailIfExists);
```