# Save Image to Phone Gallery. {Windows Phone 8.1}

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have the Uri of the image I want to save and I am able to display it.How can I use this Uri to save that particular image to my phone gallery? What privileges will the app require?

Comment: Just one web search away: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27430294/2653134

Comment: Thanks! Should have gone through this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to check the "Picture Library" in the package.appmanifest file under capabilities section (along with any other library you think you might use).

The capabilities section makes the phone ask the user for permission to use whatever you check.

As for saving the picture from a URI, you will need to get into the storage file and save your URI as an image from there.
Check this link for better info: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/769c9a6c-961c-47ea-bddf-a381db932289/saving-an-image-from-the-web-to-the-saved-pictures-folder-in-windows-phone-81-rt-c?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: Thank you so much! Brief but very helpful.